# Grouping of digits with siunitx different when using alignment character (&) or not

Tags: siunitx, grouping

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 \sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 6}
  l
  &= \frac{\SI{10000}{\m}+\SI{10000}{\m}}{\num{10000}}\\
  &= \SI{2}{\m}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 \sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 6}
  l
  = \frac{\SI{10000}{\m}+\SI{10000}{\m}}{\num{10000}}
  = \SI{2}{\m}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Why is the minimum grouping of digits not change to six in the first example (as I would like it to) while it is in the second example?

P.S. In this particular example, I know grouping of five digits is 'the best' choice but it's just to illustrate my point. Also, I know I shouldn't use `align` for one-lined expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each component with the `align`-like constructions form a group. As such, changes - like (re)definitions, including `\sisetup` are local to that cell. Move `\sisetup` to a cell of interest and you'll see a different output. However, these things should ideally be set globally (outside the `align`-like environment).

Comment: I see. So should I set it like `{\sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 6}
\begin{align*}
  l
  &= \frac{\SI{10000}{\m}+\SI{10000}{\m}}{\num{10000}}\\
  &= \SI{2}{\m}
\end{align*}}`?

Comment: Why not include `\sisetup` in your preamble?

Comment: Because I don't want the same grouping of digits all the way through the document.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: For a localized change, I would suggest `\SI[<options>]{<num>}{<unit>}`.